# Uploadify open browse dialog when click on a custom picture

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I am using Uploadify to upload pictures.

I am having a picture, and I want to Uploadify open the browse files dialog after clicking on the image, how can I achieve this ?

Here is my code

```
$("#btnAddImg").click(function() {
    Uploading(); 
});

function Uploading() {

    var a = $("input#Id").val();

    alert("uploading" + a);

    $("#fileuploader").uploadify({
        'uploader': '/Scripts/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'cancelImg': '/Content/Images/icones/cancel.png',
        //'buttonText': 'Select Image',
        //'buttonImg': '/Content/Images/icones/picture-add-icon.png',
        'script': 'Home/Upload',
        'folder': a,
        'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
        'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
        'multi': true,
        'auto': true
    });
}
```

Ps: I don' t want to use the 'buttonImg': integrate property, as I want uploadify to load only after clicking my custom image ( as behind the scene I want to get the dynamic folder path and pass to uploadify)

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Hi, The problem is that when I click on my custom picture to browse the pictures to upload, I am having the uploadify button "Select Files", I need to go one more step to get to the browse files dialog to select the files, I want to get rid of the "select files" button

Comment: Argh ok. http://www.uploadify.com/ is down, so its i cant see their docs :(

Comment: yes, indeed, uploadify.com is down, however still reacheable bizarely on iphone

Comment: I finally use a workaround, I am using the default property buttonImg: and the method uploadifySettings to update the dynamic folder path, the code is $("#fileuploader").uploadifySettings('folder', id.toString());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better solution -> http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

See Examples -> http://valums.com/files/2009/ajax-upload/demo-jquery.htm

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, I will have a look on the solutions proposed, they seems to be great, meanwhile, If I can find out a quick solution for uploadify would be great as it is already integrated in my project

Comment: broken link, I really needed this solution. :/